# Prolog pattern matching

Tags: prolog, pattern-matching

If I have a term H which is either of the form
`a > b` or
`a`
where a and b are constants (although not necessarily named a and b), how can I check the form of H?

Neither
`H == (X > Y)`
nor
`H =:= (X > Y)`
doesn't work.

Comment: In SWI-Prolog, I can do `H = (X > Y)`. Can you try on your side?

Comment: @nhahtdh this the answer, I think. `?- (1 > 2) = (X > Y).
X = 1,
Y = 2.`

Comment: `X = (a > b).` then `X = (_ > _)` will be true, and can be used to check for the form `X > Y`. You don't even need `X` and `Y` (unless you want to know their values). To check if `X` is just an atom (like `a`) use `atom(X)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need here is unification `=/2`:

```
H = (X > Y)
```

As for the 2 alternatives that you have tried, they are not what you want:

> `@Term1 == @Term2`
>
> `True` if `Term1` is equivalent to `Term2`. A variable is only identical to a sharing variable.

---

> `+Expr1 =:= +Expr2`
>
> `True` if expression `Expr1` evaluates to a number equal to `Expr2`.

Explanation are taken from swi-prolog.org documentation, but since these are ISO features, a ISO-complient implementation should not have any difference.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to match patterns using [subsumes_term/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=subsumes_term/2), since it matches patterns without binding variables. One pattern can match several different terms, so the pattern can be re-used:

```
:- initialization(main).
:- set_prolog_flag('double_quotes','chars').

main :-
    Pattern = (X>1),
    subsumes_term(Pattern,A>1),
    subsumes_term(Pattern,5>1),
    subsumes_term(Pattern,6>1).
```

In this example, the variables `X` or `A` are unchanged.